# 2D: Aim at the Mouse/Triangle proportion

Tags: java, geometry

Let's say I've got xMouse, yMouse, xPlayer, yPlayer, and length as integers. the mouse ones are where the mouse cursor is, and the player ones are obviously where the player is. I want to make the player aim at the target, but I do not want to use Graphics2D. I want to use `g.drawLine` to draw a line from the player, about 20 units forward, aiming at the target. Using the Triangle Proportionality Theorem, I should be able to use the following proportion to aim at the player:

```
(20 / dist) = (xCoord / xMouse - xPlayer)
//Where xCoord is the x pixels. The above would be the similar for the y axis.
```

which can be written as:

```
xCoord = ((xCoord - xPlayer) * 20) / dist(xMouse, xPlayer);
```

But in my case, it kind of works. When I do this for the y axis too and draw this point (xCoord, yCoord) with fillOval, I get a "debug" circle over by (0, 0), and it moves around when the mouse moves. Since I use `xCoord - xPlayer`, it should work (in my mind). Also, not only is this odd, but the distance from the mouse and the player also dictates the distance of that circle from (0, 0). It should be constant though.

If you could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, that would be great. Thank you. It should be easy with the simple geometry in the picture below, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out!!

[image: Example in a picture form.]

Answer (score 0):

i use this code for a little game but if u change the speed to ur distance then it shoudl work

```
   int angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(target.x - x, target.y - y));
   this.position.x += speed * Math.sin(angle);
   this.position.z += speed * Math.cos(angle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do step by step calculations.
Vector from player to mouse is:
`V = (Vx, Vy) = (xMouse-xPlayer, yMouse-yPlayer)`
It's length:
`VLen = Sqrt((xMouse-xPlayer)^2 + (yMouse-yPlayer)^2) //use Math.Hypot if available`
Unit (normalized) vector:
`uV = (uVx, uVy) = (Vx/Vlen, Vy/Vlen)`
Vector from player to mouse with length 20:
`V20 = 20 * uV = (20 * Vx/Vlen, 20 * Vy/Vlen)`

so final coordinates are:

```
xCoord = xPlayer + 20 * Vx/Vlen
yCoord = yPlayer + 20 * Vy/Vlen
```